# How to retrieve entity relationships after save?

Tags: java, rest, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hypermedia

I'm developing a RESTful webservice with [spring-data](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data) as its data access layer, backed by JPA/Hibernate.
It is very common to have relationships between domain entities. For example, imagine an entity `Product` which ***has*** a `Category` entity.

Now, when the client `POST`s a `Product` representation to a JAX-RS method. That method is annotated with `@Transactional` to wrap every repository operation in a transaction. Of course, the client only sends the `id` of an already existing `Category`, not the whole representation, just a reference (the foreign key).

In that method, if I do this:

```
entity = repository.save(entity);
```

the variable `entity` now has a `Category` with only the `id` field set. This didn't surprise me. I wasn't expecting a save (SQL insert) to retrieve information on related objects. But I need the whole `Product` object and related entities to be able to return to the user.

Then I did this:

```
entity = repository.save(entity);
entity = repository.findOne(entity.getId());
```

that is, retrieve the object after persisting it, **within the same transaction/session**.

To my surprise, the variable `entity` didn't change anything. Actually, the database didn't even get a single select query.
This is related with Hibernate's cache. For some reason, when in the same transaction, a find does not retrieve the whole object graph if that object was previously persisted.

With Hibernate, the solution appears to be to use `session.refresh(entity)` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290860/hibernate-calling-get-after-save-on-the-newly-created-record-within-the-same) and [this](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=953267)). Makes sense.

**But how can I achieve this with spring data?**

I would like to avoid to create repetitive custom repositories. I think that this functionality should be a part of spring data itslef (Some people already reported this in spring data's forum: [thread1](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?111814-Entity-refresh-using-spring-data-jpa-module), [thread2](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?128414-Refreshing-entities-using-spring-data)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**

References between entities in the web layer need to be made explicit by using links and should not be hidden behind semi-populated object instances. References in the persistence layer are represented by object references. So there should be a dedicated step transforming one (the link) into the other (the fully populated object reference).

**Details**

It's an anti-pattern to hand around backend ids as such and assume the marshaling binding doing the right thing. So the clients should rather work with links and hand those to the server to indicate they want to establish a connection between an already existing resource and one about to be created.

So assuming you have the existing `Category` exposed via `/categories/4711`, you could post to your server:

```
POST /products
{ links : [ { rel : "category", href : "/categories/4711" } ],
  // further product data
}
```

The server would the instantiate a new `Product` instance, populate it with additional data and eventually populate the associations as follows:

1. Identify properties to be populated by looking up the link relation types (e.g. the `category` property here.
2. Extract the backend identifier from the given URI
3. Use the according repository to lookup the related entity instance
4. Set it on the root entity

So in your example boiling down to:

```
Product product = new Product();
// populate primitive properties
product.setCategory(categoryRepository.findOne(4711));
productRepository.save(product);
```

Simply posting something like this to the server:

```
POST /products
{ category : {
    id : 1, … },
  … 
}
```

is suboptimal for a lot of reasons:

1. You want the persistence provider to implicitly persist a `Product` instance and at the same time 'recognize' that the `Category` instance referred to (actually consisting of an id only) is not meant to be persisted but updated with the data of the already existing `Category`? That's quite a bit of magic I'd argue.
2. You essentially impose the data structure you use to POST to the server to the persistence layer by expecting it to transparently deal with the way you decided to do POSTs. That's not a responsibility of the persistence layer but the web layer. The whole purpose of a web layer is to mitigate between the characteristics of an HTTP based protocol using representations and links to a backend service.

Comment: Great answer!
Aren't we already hand around backend ids in the single resource urls, for example `/categories/4711`?

Comment: Also, we need to parse the linked Category URL and obtain its id. This should be provided by some HATEOAS helper or library. Not sure how can I accomplish this elegantly.

HATEOAS seems to be more extensive than I thought. :)

Comment: I used `/categories/4711` as readable example, but the URI could be `/fe6325a27` which makes the need for an additional mapping step more obvious I guess. In [Spring HATEOAS](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-hateoas) we already have API to build `Link` instances pointing to controller methods and JAX-RS resources. Unfortunately you're the only one who knows where in the URI you find the backend id (e.g. `/categories/4711` VS. `/categories?id=4711`. Even be a complete mapping step could be necessary as shown above. So it's hard to build generic support for that.

Comment: I see that you are a contributer to spring-hateoas. Can you tell me how well does it support JAX-RS, specially regarding ResourceAssemblers? Is there any example available with JAX-RS? I'm having some problems in JaxRsLinkBuilder, when it tries to execute `new JaxRsLinkBuilder(ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentServletMapping())`. I get `Could not find current request via RequestContextHolder`.
I've tried to use this library in the past. It appears to address HATEOAS very good, but never managed to get it to work with JAX-RS.
Just found the example repository with regular Spring Contollers

Comment: I wasn't using the latest spring-hateoas. I wasn't using EntityLinks. Is it possible to `@EnableEntityLinks` in xml? I'm a bit lost on how to use programmatic configuration in a Spring+JAX-RS application. Which "WebInitializer" should I subclass/implement? Maybe I should create a new SO question.

Comment: Short: no XML support yet, JavaConfig is the way to go. Further SO questions are probably a good idea. Generally you might wanna have a look at Spring RESTBucks to see of how this can work… https://github.com/olivergierke/spring-restbucks

Comment: @OliverDrotbohm 1) I thought hateoas `links` are only a part of `GET` response and shouldn't be part of `POST`. I never thought of this.   2)What benefits would I get if I used DTOs and for every child association I need to make a separate call. Whole puprose of DTOs(saving server calls) is lost then.