# Spring data JPA save() return less/incorrect child and parent association mapping fields

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am saving the `Article` entity which is having `@ManyToOne` with `Category`.

```
@Entity
class Article{
  private Integer articleId;
  private String title;
  private String content;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
  private Category category;
}


@Entity
class Category{
  private Byte categoryId;
  private String name;
  private String summary;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "category")
  private List<Article> articles = new ArrayList<>();
}


//the service class method to save Article entity
pubic Article save(Article article){
  return articleRepository.save(article);
}
```

I have omitted `JPA` annotations and few other details.
This is the data I am sending:

```
{
    "title": " this is that",
    "content": "this is that this is that this is that hh",
    "category": {
        "categoryId": 1
    }
}
```

This article does get saved and it return me the saved article but the `category` contains only the fields which I send into the POST request. e.g if I send only `categoryId` into the POST request, then in response I receive only `categoryId` and other fields as `null`. This is the response I get

```
{
    "articleId": 1,
    "title": " this is that",
    "content": "this is that this is that this is that hh",
    "category": {
        "categoryId": 1,
        "name": null,
        "summary": null
    }
}
```

And If the send category `name` for the category into the request, then I get `name` also in response, even **if that name is incorrect**.

Please note that the category is pre-filled data into the database and new entries are not allowed.

Already tried:

1. Setting `@OneToMany` to `EAGER` in `Category`.
2. using `saveAndFlush()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to retrieve entity relationships after save?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14581594/how-to-retrieve-entity-relationships-after-save)

Comment: You need to make sure category object is saved first before adding relationships. Check also @Cascade annotation. And in the end - try to replace EAGER to LAZY.

Comment: @Hadi yes, thanks.