# Hibernate: ID of entity added to list

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Data JPA + Hibernate. I need to get ID of entity after it's added to a list of other entity and saved. Here is the code:

```java
@Entity
public class Product extends AbstractAuditable<Long> {


    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", nullable = false)
    private List<Feedback> feedbacks = new ArrayList<Feedback>();

    ...

}


@Entity
public class Feedback extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Product product;

    ...

}


public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {

}


Feedback feedback = new Feedback();
product.getFeedbacks().add(feedback);
productRepository.saveProduct(product);
feedback.getId(); // returns null
```

How to correctly get ID of feedback after it's saved?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute refresh method from Hibernate Session interface (or EntityManager interface) to "re-read the state from the given instance from the underlying database". Example:

```
session.save(object);
session.flush();
session.refresh(object);
```

You can find more information here:

- [Hibernate calling get() after save() on the newly created record within the same transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290860/hibernate-calling-get-after-save-on-the-newly-created-record-within-the-same)
- [Hibernate: Refresh, Evict, Replicate and Flush](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8137057/hibernate-refresh-evict-replicate-and-flush)
- [Hibernate calling get() after save() on the newly created record within the same transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290860/hibernate-calling-get-after-save-on-the-newly-created-record-within-the-same)
- [Force refresh of collection JPA entityManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15089177/force-refresh-of-collection-jpa-entitymanager)